# install npm package from bitbucket without npm-shrinkwrap.json

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, npm, npm-shrinkwrap

**The question:**

In NodeJS how can I ignore the shrinkwrap of a dependency "Package B" on an "npm install" in the higher order "Project A", when "Package B" comes from a private repo.

**The background:**

Let's say we develop on a private npm-package "fancy-frontend" and got a CI system for that, which requires to keep a npm-shrinkwrap.json next to the package.json (to have a deterministic snapshot of all dependencies).

In another repo we do the development on the higher system with the node project "fancy-system". That project has a dependency to a tagged version of "fancy-frontend". So we do an install of that project with the command

`npm i git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myteam/fancy-frontend.git#v1.0.2 --save`

Because of the existing npm-shrinkwrap.json in our sub-dependency "fancy-frontend" npm seems to use that sub-shrinkwrap and builds up a complete independent package-tree within the "fancy-frontend" modules. Ending up with this huge dependency file tree:

```
fancy-system/
   package.json
   npm-shrinkwrap.json
   node_modules/
     react-16.13.1
     fancy-frontend/
        package.json
        npm-shrinkwrap.json
        node-modules/
          react-16.13.1      // e.g. same react dep as in parent, but has it's own instance
          other-deps
     other deps
```

NOTE: I added react as sample dependency that should be shared by both modules, but is not.

**The issues:**

We got a huge dependency mass with a lot of duplicated packages (although "fancy-system" and "fancy-frontend" are referencing the same version!).
We got issues with react and multiple instances (although we set react as peer dependency in "fancy-frontend"!).

Comment: a workaround seems to be using yarn, that creates a slim dependency tree on a single layer and works with react